# Running php script via Jenkins Execute shell

Tags: php, jenkins, jenkins-php

I am trying to run php script via execute shell in Jenkins but it seems i am missing something.

here is my command in execute shell of Jenkins

```
#!/usr/bin/php

php /home/admin/reports/test.php"
```

I am not getting any error in console output.

and when i try these commands:

```
#!/bin/bash    
php /home/admin/reports/test.php"
```

then I get error which says `failed to open stream: Permission denied in` `/home/admin/reports/test.php"` .

Comment: no error. but when i run the same commands in CLI linux then this script is executed and i get results that i need. but with Jenkins nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins, with default installation, will be run under `jenkins` user. That user has no access to your `/home/admin` home directory. The `Permission denied` is pretty self-explanatory.

- Either give `jenkins` user read access to `/home/admin` (not recommended)
- Or place the file into `/home/jenkins` directory (not best solution either)
- Or better yet, have the file available in shared location accessible by both, preferably the job's workspace that is populated through the SCM (recommended).

Comment: thanks for windows users these minor things are sometimes a really headache